# iPhone Table View with alphabet

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

How I can add a Alphabet section to the Table View?

Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: it called _section index_, and you will find information in your _Bible_ about it: https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 5):

You need to  implement 2 methods of UITableView for this i.e. sectionIndexTitlesForTableView return alphabet array in this & sectionForSectionIndexTitle.
Check this tutorial for more info:

http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/indexed-uitableview-tutorial/